# Plugin for Bukkit that will allow me to log all changes on the server

Tags: bukkit

I'm looking for a plugin that will allow me to log and rollback any change to the world that was made on the server. For example, if one user destroys another user's house, I would like the ability for me to restore that destruction.

Features I am looking for:

- Find all changes in the world with a command

  - Find changes from one specific player
  - Find changes which involved a specific block/item
- Ability to select the area I wish to rollback and then choose what player/block/item I wish to rollback and on a specified date
- Ability to rollback any chest(including contents)/block
- Should have SQL support, but not a requirement

Answer (score 3):

[Prism](http://discover-prism.com/) is a great Bukkit logging program. It supports:

- Configurable rollback radius
- "Previewing" a rollback so that it's only visible to the person who ran the command
- Limiting a rollback by player, time, block, type of event, and many other parameters
- SQLite and MySQL
- Can rollback the contents of chests